# cairocffi throws an error with pango

Tags: cairo, pycairo, python-cffi, pangocairo

```
context = cairocffi.Context(surface)
# pangocairo.pango_cairo_set_antialias(cairo.ANTIALIAS_SUBPIXEL)
context.translate(movex, movey)
context.rotate(twist)
layout = gobject_ref(pangocairo.pango_cairo_create_layout(context._pointer))
```

In the last line of this code cairocffi give a weird error

```
TypeError: initializer for ctype 'cairo_t *' appears indeed to be 'cairo_t *', but the types are different (check that you are not e.g. mixing up different ffi instances)
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: There is some mix of different instances of cffi.FFI().  Normally, only one should be created per library, but in this case I guess that cairocffi creates more, maybe by mistake.